# rake aborted error while implementing db:drop in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am new to rails.I was trying `rake db:drop` but am getting the following error

```
rake aborted!
(<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 21 column 12
/home/chiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `database_configuration'
/home/chiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:drop => db:load_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am installing on `ubuntu`.While working the same code for windows environment it seems to work perfectly

My database.yml is as follows:-

```
# PostgreSQL v0.8.x
#   gem install pg
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: lib_development
  pool: 5
  username: chiron
  password: 

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: lib_test
  pool: 5
   username: chiron
  password: 

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: lib_production
  pool: 5
   username: chiron
  password:
```

Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have redundant spacebar in config

```
  pool: 5
   username: chiron # << here
  password:
```

Comment: Now getting the following error:-

ls/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
 from /home/chiron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails